# Primavera p6 8.1, Exception EstringListError in module PM.exe at 00028F85 list index out of bounds（0）

Tags: primavera

about Primavera P6 V8.1:

1. login P6, configure database connetions.
2. delete all dababase connections.
3. then could not login P6. error info “Exception EstringListError in module PM.exe at 00028F85 list index out of bounds（0）”
4. try to reinstall p6 client ，the error always exists

I will be highly appreciated if you could sovle this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need at least one P6 Database Configuration, which is configured successfully to the P6 database (PMDB), to login with a P6 application user account.

If this error occurred when you configured PMDB via Database Configuration utility, do the following:

> Copy Prmbootstrap.xml file from the All Users folder or Default
>   profile, to the current user's profile.

You can find Prmbootstrap.xml file in:

> C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Oracle\Primavera P6\P6 Optional
>   Client (if P6 Optional Client)
>   C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Oracle\Primavera P6\P6 Professional
>   (if P6 Professional)

Hope it will help.

Yogi